# Define a mapping $f: I \subset \mathbb{R} \to B$ where $B$ is the set of all binary strings of finite length $l$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory, algorithms

Here are two attempts:

**Attempt 1.**

Let $r \in I$ where $I=[a,b]$. Define $f(r)=r_1 r_2 r_3 ...r_l$ where $r_i \in \{0,1\}$ for $i=\{1,2,...,l\}$

Let $N=\inf \{ z \in \mathbb{Z}^+ | z \leq\dfrac{\log(l)}{log(2)} \}$

for $k=1$ subdivide the parent interval $I_0=[a_0,b_0]$ into 2 disjoint sub-intervals
so that we have $I_1=[a_0, \frac{a_0 +b_0}{2}) \cup [\dfrac{a_0 +b_0}{2}, b_0]$ where the left subinterval is labelled as $I_{11}$ and the right subinterval as $I_{12}$
then for $k=2$ subdivide each subinterval in $K_1$ into two disjoint subintervals through the midpoint so we have $[a_0, \dfrac{3a_0 +b_0}{2^2}) \cup [\dfrac{3a_0 +b_0}{2^2},\dfrac{a_0 +b_0}{2}) \cup[\dfrac{a_0 +b_0}{2} , \dfrac{a_0 +2b_0}{2^2}) \cup [\dfrac{a_0 +2b_0}{2^2},b_0]$ where the subintervals are labelled as $I_{21}, I_{22}, I_{23}, I_{24}$. Repeat the process $N$ times.
so at $k=N$ we have $2^N$ disjoint subintervals each of length $\frac{l(I_0)}{2^N}$

Now lets define $r_i$. I find it best to describe it algorithmically:

*for* i=1:$N$

$q=2^i$

**for** j=1:$q$

$r_{ij}=0$ if $r \in I_{ij}$

o.w, $r_{ij}=1$

**end(for)**

*end(for)*

---

**Q1**: is there another way for defining $f$ or another compact way of describing the above rule of $f$?
**Q2:** Also if I want to define another function $g: B \to I \subset \mathbb{R}$ I thought of the following, is there another idea?

let $r=r_1 r_2 ..r_l$

1. Subdivide the interval $I=[a,b]$ into $l$ disjoint subintervals
2. For all $i$ st $i=1,...,l$. Define $g(r)=\sum_{i=1}^l r_i \dfrac{b_i + a_i}{2}$

---

Comment: By "cardinality" do you mean "length"?

Comment: Yes. I mean the length